# Spring security: how to stop logging access denied exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring-boot app with oauth2. My i have a HttpSecurity more less like this

```
.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Every time anonymous user tries to access api, spring logs full stack trace of AccessDeniedException. This behavior is not an application bug so i don't want any exceptions nor stacktraces in my logs.

I would prefer to do that without raising logging level to warn as there is plenty of useful debugging messages from spring-security. I just don't want exceptions when there is no problem with the app

Comment: The exception is logged for debugging purposes... You shouldn't enable anything lower then WARN in your live system imho... Just disable the debug logging.

Comment: Just to make it clear, you need not to raise log level for all Spring Security classes, just for the exception logging classes. But  M. Deinum is right, in a live system debug should be disabled.

Comment: Maybe he just activates the debug few minutes with Actuator, who cares, debugging  is not related to the question...

I am facing the situation and I agree with @piotrek printing the stackstrace in such a situation is just useless because bring nothing interesting.

I tried to add custom servlet filters and custom accessDeniedHandlers but notthing works, I never have the hand on this exception.